# Starting Hadoop without ssh'ing to localhost

Tags: linux, hadoop

I've a very tricky situation in my hand. I'm installing Hadoop on few nodes which run Ubuntu 12.04 and our IT guys have created a user "hadoop" for me to use on all the nodes. The issue with this user is that it does not allow ssh on localhost because of some security constraints. So, I'm not able to start Hadoop daemons at all.

I can connect to itself using "ssh hadoop@hadoops_address" but not using loopback address. I also cannot make any changes to the /etc/hosts. Is there a way I can tell Hadoop to ssh to itself using  "ssh hadoop@hadoops_address"  instead of   "ssh hadoop@localhost"?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop reads the hostname from "masters" and "slaves" file which is present inside conf dir,
edit the file and change the value from localhost to hadoops_address.
This should fix your problem.